# Counting categories within subsets of years and divide by total count within the subset

Tags: python, pandas

I am counting the number of negative numbers and positive numbers within each year. Ultimately I want to get the percent of negative and positive for each year.

I tried groupby year and counting the categories, but the new columns appears with no name.

```
    df1= df.groupby(['Year','Count of Negative/Positive Margins'])['Count of Negative/Positive Margins'].count()

    df1.head()
    Out[194]: 
    Year  Count of Negative/Positive Margins
    2005  1                                     4001
          2                                     1373
    2006  1                                     4046
          2                                     1304
    2007  1                                     4156
    Name: Count of Negative/Positive Margins, dtype: int64
```

This my expected output:

```
    2005  1                                     74%
          2                                     26%
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Try `df.groupby('Year')['Count of Negative/Positive Margins'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100`

Comment: Why would the two add up to 98%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with grouping only column `Year` and parameter `normalize=True`, then multiple by `100`, round by [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html), convert to strings and add `%`:

```
df = (df.groupby('Year')['Count of Negative/Positive Margins']
        .value_counts(normalize=True)
        .mul(100)
        .round()
        .astype(str)
        .add('%')
        .reset_index(name='percentage')
       )
```